# Kotlin lambdas without using objects

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I am trying to convert from java to kotlin. The current java interface is something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void foo(int x, int y);
}

MyInterface testing = (int a, int b) -> System.out.print("TESTING");
```

My current kotlin conversion is:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun foo(x:Int, y:Int)
}

val kotlinConversion = object: MyInterface {
    override fun foo(x: Int, y: Int) {
        println("TESTING")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write the variable `kotlinConversion` such that it is similar to the one in java without having to override the function?

Comment: Do you need it to be an interface? A function type could potentially work just as well.

Comment: I think in order for any of us to answer, we need a better idea of your use case. What you have in Kotlin is not how one would do it in Kotlin. On the other hand, if you have a functional interface in Java, you can use a Lambda, and it will get cast/processed correctly.

If it's all Kotlin code, then as chris said, you'll likely want a function type.

Something like val kotlinConversion: (Int, Int) -> Unit = {x,y -> println("TESTING") }

Comment: This has been discussed here in kotlin forum.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-sam-traits-as-lambda-functions/279
@Mikezx6r answer is the suggested solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without  override the function you can directly use like this way

```
var kotlinConversion = { a: Int, b: Int -> print("TESTING") }
```